# Utilize swiping function on mobile device to navigate array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, touchswipe

I am working on a simple online portfolio that displays a single image from an array with a corresponding caption and a link to the next or previous image in the array. I would like to utilize the swiping function of mobile devices so that someone who views the site on such a device will not have to use the hyperlink to view the next or previous image (the link is small and hyperlinks trigger the navigation bar on iphones which is disruptive). Is there a way to make a swiping motion link to another page or do I need to have all of the images available on one page and use JS to show one image at a time while hiding the others?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
<tr valign="middle"><td align="center" colspan="2">

    <img src="31.jpg" width="40%" style="padding-top:38px; max-width:672px">
    
</td></tr>
<tr valign="bottom"><td style="padding:0 0 22 16" height="38">

    Cover for a book of photographs
    
</td><td align="right" style="padding:0 16 22 0">
 
    <a href="10.html">&lt;</a>&nbsp; 01 / 10 &nbsp;<a href="2.html">&gt;</a>
    
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin)** this way:

```
$("#panelElement").swipe({
    swipeLeft: function(){
        $("a#anchorNextImage").trigger("click");
    },
    swipeRight: function(){
        $("a#anchorPreviousImage").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.